# Regex to grab the data from an address string

Tags: regex, regex-group

I have an address string that looks like:

```
#12 1320 Water Street|Kelowna, British Columbia V1Y9P4
```

I need the regex to grab these values:

```
#12
1320
Water street
```

I've tried the next one:

```
([\w\d]+)\s(.+?)\s(.+?)\|
```

But I can also have no first value (#12). 
For example:

```
1320 Water Street|Kelowna, British Columbia V1Y9P4
```

And now my regex won't work.

Is it possible to have one regex to grab the data I need in both situations (with first value \ without first value)?

Comment: I think you're looking for the `?` quantifier. It matches either zero or one times. Just apply it behind your match for #12.

Comment: Try libpostal. You need something a bit more sophisticated.

Comment: Try [`^(?:(#\d+)\s+)?(\d+)\s+([^|]+)`](https://regex101.com/r/1p8ndT/1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
^(#\d+ )?(\w+) ([^|]+)
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/SHKV8B/1)**

[image]

Comment: How did you make this image? Pretty interesting.